# Kivy missing 1 positional argument (self)

Tags: python, kivy

Sooooo
I'm still working on that school project from my last question and this time it is a prototype, not a test. It is supposed to solve equations. I allready wrote the code in vanilla Python and TkInter and that is working. Also it has parts of german in it. My struggle is how to get strings from the TextInput to the proccesing part and putting it out to the Label Lös. So here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button

a=42

class übung(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(übung, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 3
        self.fill1 = Label(text = "")
        self.label1 = Label(text = "Sagen sie ihre Gleichung")
        self.fill2 = Label(text = "")
        self.links = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.label2 = Label(text = '=')
        self.rechts = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.fill3 = Label(text = '')
        self.btn1 = Button(text="Lösen")
        self.btn1.bind(on_press=self.einfach())
        self.fill4 = Label(text = '')
        self.fill5 = Label(text = '')
        self.btn2 = Button(text="Mit Rechenweg lösen")
        self.btn2.bind(on_press=self.einfachS)
        self.fill6 = Label(text = '')
        self.fill7 = Label(text = '')
        self.lös = Label(text = '')
        self.fill8 = Label(text = '')
        self.fill9 = Label(text = '')
        self.rech1 = Label(text = '')
        self.fill10 = Label(text = '')
        self.fill11 = Label(text = '')
        self.rech2 = Label(text = '')
        self.fill12 = Label(text = '')
        self.fill13 = Label(text = '')
        self.rech3 = Label(text = '')
        self.fill14 = Label(text = '')
        self.fill15 = Label(text = '')
        self.rech4 = Label(text = '')


        self.add_widget(self.fill1)
        self.add_widget(self.label1)
        self.add_widget(self.fill2)
        self.add_widget(self.links)
        self.add_widget(self.label2)
        self.add_widget(self.rechts)
        self.add_widget(self.fill3)
        self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.add_widget(self.fill6)
        self.add_widget(self.fill7)
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)
        self.add_widget(self.fill8)
        self.add_widget(self.fill9)
        self.add_widget(self.lös)
        self.add_widget(self.fill4)
        self.add_widget(self.fill5)
        self.add_widget(self.rech1)
        self.add_widget(self.fill10)
        self.add_widget(self.fill11)
        self.add_widget(self.rech2)
        self.add_widget(self.fill12)
        self.add_widget(self.fill13)
        self.add_widget(self.rech3)
        self.add_widget(self.fill14)
        self.add_widget(self.fill15)
        self.add_widget(self.rech4)





    def einfach(event, self):
        r = self.rechts.text
        l = self.links.text
        x = 'x'
        if x in l:
            r1,r2 = r.split ('+')                    
            rr = float(r1) + float(r2)
            lr, ll = l.split('x')
            lr = float(lr)
            end = rr/lr
            end = float (end)
            self.lös.text = end
        elif x in r:
            l1,l2 = l.split ('+')                    
            ll = float(l1) + float(l2)
            rl, rr = r.split('x')
            rl = float(rl)
            end = ll/rl
            end = float(end)
            self.lös.text = end



    def einfachS(self, event):
        print ('nein')



class App(App):
     def build(self):
        return übung()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().run()
```

As you see it is very compact but i think it is only readyy for around 1 %
So yeah.
Thanks in advance, me

Comment: `def einfach(event, self)`... Did you mean to switch the order there ?

Comment: Oh yes. But when I switch it, it now says that event is missing.

Comment: Remove parentheses. `on_press=self.einfach()`

Comment: Now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
self.btn1.bind(on_press=self.einfach())
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
result = self.einfach()
self.btn1.bind(on_press=result)
```

When you bind functions to buttons you must give the button a *callable*. That is, a *reference* to a function. Instead, you are calling a function and passing in the result.

The solution is to change your bindings to be like the following (note the lack of `()`):

```
self.btn1.bind(on_press=self.einfach)
```

Also, you need to change this:

```
def einfach(event, self):
```

... to this:

```
def einfach(self, event):
```